# Play and record audio simultaneously in real-time with Pydub and Streamlit (streamlit-webrtc)

Tags: python, audio, webrtc, streamlit, pydub

I'm building a web application for acoustic measurements.
I would like the user to be able to play a sinusoidal sweep and record it simultaneously.
The playback and the recording must be in sync.

I'm using streamlit, streamlit-webrtc and pydub, as sounddevice is sadly unusable in an online settings as far as I understand.

Unfortunately I'm still a beginner and I'm having trouble understanding this code that I found in the streamlit-webrtc examples, especially the `app_sendonly_audio` function:

```
# import asyncio
import logging
import queue
import threading

# import urllib.request
from pathlib import Path
from typing import List, NamedTuple, Optional

# import av
# import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pydub
import streamlit as st

# from aiortc.contrib.media import MediaPlayer

from numba import jit
from scipy import signal
from scipy.io import wavfile

# from maad import sound
# from maad import util

from streamlit_webrtc import (
    RTCConfiguration,
    WebRtcMode,
    # WebRtcStreamerContext,
    webrtc_streamer,
)

HERE = Path(__file__).parent

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

RTC_CONFIGURATION = RTCConfiguration(
    {"iceServers": [{"urls": ["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"]}]}
)


def main():
    st.header("WebRTC demo")

    pages = {
        "WebRTC is sendonly and audio frames are visualized with matplotlib (sendonly)": app_sendonly_audio,
        # noqa: E501
        "Plot audio representation with scikit-maad": app_room_measurements,
    }
    page_titles = pages.keys()

    page_title = st.sidebar.selectbox(
        "Choose the app mode",
        page_titles,
    )
    st.subheader(page_title)

    page_func = pages[page_title]
    page_func()

    logger.debug("=== Alive threads ===")
    for thread in threading.enumerate():
        if thread.is_alive():
            logger.debug(f"  {thread.name} ({thread.ident})")


def app_sendonly_audio():
    """A sample to use WebRTC in sendonly mode to transfer audio frames
    from the browser to the server and visualize them with matplotlib
    and `st.pyplot`."""
    webrtc_ctx = webrtc_streamer(
        key="sendonly-audio",
        mode=WebRtcMode.SENDONLY,
        audio_receiver_size=256,
        rtc_configuration=RTC_CONFIGURATION,
        media_stream_constraints={"audio": True},
    )

    fig_place = st.empty()

    fig, [ax_time, ax_freq] = plt.subplots(
        2, 1, gridspec_kw={"top": 1.5, "bottom": 0.2}
    )

    sound_window_len = 5000  # 5s
    sound_window_buffer = None
    while True:
        if webrtc_ctx.audio_receiver:
            try:
                audio_frames = webrtc_ctx.audio_receiver.get_frames(timeout=1)
            except queue.Empty:
                logger.warning("Queue is empty. Abort.")
                break

            sound_chunk = pydub.AudioSegment.empty()
            for audio_frame in audio_frames:
                sound = pydub.AudioSegment(
                    data=audio_frame.to_ndarray().tobytes(),
                    sample_width=audio_frame.format.bytes,
                    frame_rate=audio_frame.sample_rate,
                    channels=len(audio_frame.layout.channels),
                )
                sound_chunk += sound

            if len(sound_chunk) > 0:
                if sound_window_buffer is None:
                    sound_window_buffer = pydub.AudioSegment.silent(
                        duration=sound_window_len
                    )

                sound_window_buffer += sound_chunk
                if len(sound_window_buffer) > sound_window_len:
                    sound_window_buffer = sound_window_buffer[-sound_window_len:]

            if sound_window_buffer:
                # Ref: https://own-search-and-study.xyz/2017/10/27/python%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E9%9F%B3%E5%A3%B0%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9A%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C/  # noqa
                sound_window_buffer = sound_window_buffer.set_channels(
                    1
                )  # Stereo to mono
                sample = np.array(sound_window_buffer.get_array_of_samples())

                ax_time.cla()
                times = (np.arange(-len(sample), 0)) / sound_window_buffer.frame_rate
                ax_time.plot(times, sample)
                ax_time.set_xlabel("Time")
                ax_time.set_ylabel("Magnitude")

                spec = np.fft.fft(sample)
                freq = np.fft.fftfreq(sample.shape[0], 1.0 / sound_chunk.frame_rate)
                freq = freq[: int(freq.shape[0] / 2)]
                spec = spec[: int(spec.shape[0] / 2)]
                spec[0] = spec[0] / 2

                ax_freq.cla()
                ax_freq.plot(freq, np.abs(spec))
                ax_freq.set_xlabel("Frequency")
                ax_freq.set_yscale("log")
                ax_freq.set_ylabel("Magnitude")

                fig_place.pyplot(fig)
        else:
            logger.warning("AudioReciver is not set. Abort.")
            break
```

This function records audio from the user selected input device and plots its waveform with matplotlib. I would like to be able to play a sinusoidal sweep and simultaneously record it.

This is my code for the generation of the sweep:

```
def app_room_measurements():
    audio_files_path = r"data/audio_files"
    sweep_string = ""
    inv_filter_string = ""
    ir_string = ""

    @jit(nopython=True)
    def fade(data, gain_start, gain_end):
        """
        Create a fade on an input object

        Parameters
        ----------
        :param data: The input array
        :param gain_start: The fade starting point
        :param gain_end: The fade ending point

        Returns
        -------
        data : object
            An input array with the fade applied
        """
        gain = gain_start
        delta = (gain_end - gain_start) / (len(data) - 1)
        for i in range(len(data)):
            data[i] = data[i] * gain
            gain = gain + delta

        return data

    @jit(nopython=True)
    def generate_exponential_sweep(
        sweep_duration, sr, starting_frequency, ending_frequency
    ):
        """
        Generate an exponential sweep using Farina's log sweep theory

        Parameters
        ----------
        :param sweep_duration: The duration of the excitement signal (in seconds)
        :param sr: The sampling frequency
        :param starting_frequency: The starting frequency of the excitement signal
        :param ending_frequency: The ending frequency of the excitement signal

        Returns
        -------
        exponential_sweep : array
            An array with the fade() function applied
        """
        time_in_samples = sweep_duration * sr
        exponential_sweep = np.zeros(time_in_samples, dtype=np.double)
        for n in range(time_in_samples):
            t = n / sr
            exponential_sweep[n] = np.sin(
                (2.0 * np.pi * starting_frequency * sweep_duration)
                / np.log(ending_frequency / starting_frequency)
                * (
                    np.exp(
                        (t / sweep_duration)
                        * np.log(ending_frequency / starting_frequency)
                    )
                    - 1.0
                )
            )

        number_of_samples = 50
        exponential_sweep[-number_of_samples:] = fade(
            exponential_sweep[-number_of_samples:], 1, 0
        )

        return exponential_sweep

    @jit(nopython=True)
    def generate_inverse_filter(
        sweep_duration, sr, exponential_sweep, starting_frequency, ending_frequency
    ):
        """
        Generate an inverse filter using Farina's log sweep theory

        Parameters
        ----------
        :param sweep_duration: The duration of the excitement signal (in seconds)
        :param sr: The sampling frequency
        :param exponential_sweep: The resulting array of the generate_exponential_sweep() function
        :param starting_frequency: The starting frequency of the excitement signal
        :param ending_frequency: The ending frequency of the excitement signal

        Returns
        -------
        inverse_filter : array
             The array resulting from applying an amplitude envelope to the exponential_sweep array
        """
        time_in_samples = sweep_duration * sr
        amplitude_envelope = np.zeros(time_in_samples, dtype=np.double)
        inverse_filter = np.zeros(time_in_samples, dtype=np.double)
        for n in range(time_in_samples):
            amplitude_envelope[n] = pow(
                10,
                (
                    (-6 * np.log2(ending_frequency / starting_frequency))
                    * (n / time_in_samples)
                )
                * 0.05,
            )
            inverse_filter[n] = exponential_sweep[-n] * amplitude_envelope[n]

        return inverse_filter

    def deconvolve(ir_sweep, ir_inverse):
        """
        A deconvolution of the exponential sweep and the relative inverse filter

        Parameters
        ----------
        :param ir_sweep: The resulting array of the generate_exponential_sweep() function
        :param ir_inverse: The resulting array of the generate_inverse_filter() function

        Returns
        -------
        normalized_ir : array
             An N-dimensional array containing a subset of the discrete linear deconvolution of ir_sweep with ir_inverse
        """
        impulse_response = signal.fftconvolve(
            ir_sweep, ir_inverse, mode="full"
        )  # Convolve two N-dimensional arrays using FFT

        normalized_ir = impulse_response * (1.0 / np.max(abs(impulse_response)))

        return normalized_ir

    sample_rate_option = st.selectbox("Select the desired sample rate", (44100, 48000))
    sweep_duration_option = st.selectbox("Select the duration of the sweep", (3, 7, 14))
    max_reverb_option = st.selectbox(
        "Select the expected maximum reverb decay time", (1, 2, 3, 5, 10)
    )

    st.caption(
        """
                Note that longer sweeps provide more accuracy,
                but even short sweeps can be used to measure long decays
                """
    )

    def write_wav_file(file_name, rate, data):
        save_file_path = os.path.join(audio_files_path, file_name)
        wavfile.write(save_file_path, rate, data)
        st.success(f"File successfully written to audio_files_path as:>> {file_name}")

    def play_sweep(wavefile_name):
        read_file_path = os.path.join(audio_files_path, wavefile_name)
        # Extract data and sampling rate from file
        sample_rate, data = wavfile.read(read_file_path)

        stop_button = st.button("Stop")

        if "stop_button_state" not in st.session_state:
            st.session_state.stop_button_state = False

        sd.play(data, sample_rate)

        if stop_button or st.session_state.stop_button_state:
            st.session_state.stop_button_state = True

            sd.stop()

        else:
            sd.wait()  # Wait until file is done playing

    user_input = str(st.text_input("Name your file: "))

    if user_input:
        sweep_string = user_input + "_exponential_sweep_.wav"
        inv_filter_string = user_input + "_inverse_filter_.wav"
        ir_string = user_input + "_impulse_response_.wav"

        st.write(sweep_string)

        play_button = st.button("Play")

        if "play_button_state" not in st.session_state:
            st.session_state.play_button_state = False

        if play_button or st.session_state.play_button_state:
            st.session_state.play_button_state = True

            sweep = generate_exponential_sweep(
                sweep_duration_option, sample_rate_option, 20, 24000
            )
            inv_filter = generate_inverse_filter(
                sweep_duration_option, sample_rate_option, sweep, 20, 24000
            )

            write_wav_file(file_name=sweep_string, rate=sample_rate_option, data=sweep)
            write_wav_file(
                file_name=inv_filter_string, rate=sample_rate_option, data=inv_filter
            )

            play_sweep(sweep_string)
```

The recorded sweep is deconvolved with the inversed sweep, finding the impulse response of the room.

Lastly:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os

    DEBUG = os.environ.get("DEBUG", "false").lower() not in ["false", "no", "0"]

    logging.basicConfig(
        format="[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)7s from %(name)s in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d: "
        "%(message)s",
        force=True,
    )

    logger.setLevel(level=logging.DEBUG if DEBUG else logging.INFO)

    st_webrtc_logger = logging.getLogger("streamlit_webrtc")
    st_webrtc_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    fsevents_logger = logging.getLogger("fsevents")
    fsevents_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

    main()
```

Is it possible to record simultaneously or I'm better off abandoning the idea of doing a website for this and instead focus on buildin an offline app?